# Why when Instantiate new GameObjects it's not adding tag to them?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour {

    public float spinSpeed = 2.0f;
    public int cloneTests;
    public GameObject prefab;

    private bool rotate = false;
    private bool exited = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cloneTests; i++)
        {
            GameObject Test = Instantiate(prefab);
            Test.tag = "Testing";
        }
    }
}
```

The cloning is working.

But it's not adding the tag to each GameObject.
And how can i put all the clones as childs under another GameObject ?

Comment: This how you make them childs: Test.transform.parent = this.transform; and it's working. But adding the new tag to each one is not working. All the lcones are untagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is testing already a declared tag? If you look it up in the Unity Script Reference you will find:

"Tags must be declared in the tag manager before using them"